# Can't figure out what's causing this crash (SIGABRT)

Tags: c++

My program returns a SIGABRT error whenever I try to run it. However, if I try to run it with randomNums1 set to a size which isn't 98 (i.e. 99 or 49), the program executes just fine. Below is my code for the function and then my calling of the function. 
Why does this only work for some sizes of randomNums1 and not all?

```
using namespace std;

int SelectionSort(int numbers[], int numbersSize) {
    int counter = 0;
    int i;
    int j;
    int indexSmallest;
    int temp;

    for (i = 0; i < numbersSize - 1; ++i) {
        // Find index of smallest remaining element
        indexSmallest = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < numbersSize; ++j) {
            if ( numbers[j] < numbers[indexSmallest] ) {
                indexSmallest = j;
            }
            counter++;
        }

        // Swap numbers[i] and numbers[indexSmallest]
        temp = numbers[i];
        numbers[i] = numbers[indexSmallest];
        numbers[indexSmallest] = temp;
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    int randomNums1[98];
    int total;
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++) {
        randomNums1[i] = 1 + rand() % ((1000 - 1) + 1);
    }
    total = SelectionSort(randomNums1, 99);
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: You have a few hardcoded numerical values around 98-99. Are you changing all of them to be consistent? As it stands the code is encountering a SIGABRT as expected, due to a detection of stack-smashing (as you are tampering with the stack via out-of-bound accesses). On my machine, using 49 *also* causes the program to abort, but this behavior isn't guaranteed (it's actually designed as a last-resort protection against certain security attacks/bugs and isn't guaranteed to fire in every situation)

Answer (score 0):

In

```
for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
```

`i` has a range  of [0, 98].

```
int randomNums1[98];
```

has a valid range of [0,97], so

```
randomNums1[i] = 1 + rand() % ((1000 - 1) + 1);
```

ventures out of range.

Solution: Reduce the range of `i`.

```
for (j = i + 1; j < numbersSize; ++j)
```

Also allows `j` to venture out of range.